# NSTextField clears its objectValue using NSNumberFormatter, how to prevent

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsnumberformatter

I'm using an NSTextField as a view in a NSTableCellView. I've connected an NSNumberFormatter, to display the value of NSDecimalNumber objects.
I set the object like so:
`cellView.textField.objectValue=[NSDecimalNumber notANumber];`
The text field first requests the string value for this object from the formatter. That works great.
It then requests the string value for the string the formatter just returned! Of course this fails and the text field clears its display on the next redraw.
Why does the text field store the string from the formatter as its object value? Shouldn't it only use it to display the value?

I've verified this behavior by making a subclass of NSNumberFormatter and connecting that subclass as the formatter:

```
@implementation CustomNumberFormatter
-(NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)obj {
    NSString *result=[super stringForObjectValue:obj];
    NSLog(@"string %@ for obj: %@",result,obj);
    return result;
}
@end
```

It then logs:

```
string NaN for obj: NaN
string (null) for obj: NaN{
NSColor = "NSNamedColorSpace System alternateSelectedControlTextColor";
NSFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFont 13.00 pt. P [] (0x60000004cc90) fobj=0x100d1aa20, spc=3.59\"";
NSOriginalFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFont 13.00 pt. P [] (0x60000004cc90) fobj=0x100d1aa20, spc=3.59\"";
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

(I removed some repetitions of the same, it seems it makes a few rounds of each (I test with only a single text field)).
The string object is of course the attributed version of the formatted string.

Comment: Your issue only appears to occur with NaN, other values, including ∞, work as expected. No idea if this is a bug, feature or documented somewhere.

Comment: I've tried it with general NSNumber and NSDecimalNumber objects, but they all show the exact same behavior. I've fixed it temporarily by checking the object type and if it's a string, I return it directly. Doesn't feel like it's the right way to go though.

Comment: A simple test application with just a text field and associated number formatter does not exhibit the bahaviour you describe, but a NaN does not display. So the cause of your issue would appear to be elsewhere.

Comment: I think explicitly setting the `objectValue` to a string is expected to clear the text field, as the number formatter expects an `NSNumber`. My problem is that when I set an `NSNumber` as the `objectValue`, the text field itself then tries to send a string to the number formatter, which logically fails.